# JavaFX Project with Weld also in subproject

Tags: javafx, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have the following structure:

- A JavaFX project for GUI stuff with some Service classes for that.
- A Core-Project containing the business-logic and persistence-logic.
- the core is hooked to the gui via maven:

.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.andwari.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

My goal is to provide Injection and such things with jboss weld.

I implemented it successfully in the JavaFX project with this tutorial: http://fxapps.blogspot.com/2017/10/using-cdi-20-in-javafx-application.html

So injection is working fine in that project but NOT in the subproject (the core). How do I make the core-project-classes known to the container as well? 
Tutorials and explanations on that are very rare or too specific so I have no idea how that works exactly.

My CDI setup code is basicly the same as the one in the tutorial. (https://github.com/AprendendoJava/javafx-basic-tutorials/tree/master/blog-javafx/javafx-cdi2)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
    final SeContainer container = initializer.initialize();
    container.getBeanManager().fireEvent(primaryStage, new AnnotationLiteral<StartupScene>() {});
}
```

Example:

I have a javafx controller like this:

```
public class EventPlayerSelectionController {
    ...
    @FXML
    private Button btnStartEvent;

    @Inject
    private TabPlayerService tabPlayerService;
    ...
    //someMethods
}
```

This injection works fine since that service is in the JavaFX project. But within the TabPlayerService I have:

```
public class TabPlayerService {

    @Inject
    private PlayerService playerService;
    //some methods
}
```

The PlayerService class is from the core. So the container can obviously not handle it. How do I make those classes injectable??

Comment: I think I figured it out! It was already working but I instanciated the PlayerService with "new" at another point I wasn't aware of... So I guess the whole class becomes unmanaged? Removing the "new" and instead injecting it, solved the problem!

Comment: Yes you are right, you need to let CDI handle the instance lifecycle for injection to work. Manually created classes are, by default, not handled by CDI at all.